# Concatenate strings with vb6

Tags: vb6, textbox, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate in vb6.  The operator += is not supported, and I want to do something like the code below.  I want to add more strings to a textbox as the program works down this code.  Can anyone advise what to change += to?  I know & can be used when adding one string to another, but it the example I am working on here, that doesn't seem suitable.

Thanks.

```
    If (strHomeNo <> "") Then
        txtPhoneNums = "Home: " + strHomeNo
    End If
    If (strMobileNo <> "") Then
        txtPhoneNums += "Mobile: " + strMobileNo
    End If
    If (strWorkNo <> "") Then
        txtPhoneNums += "Work: " + strWorkNo
    End If
    If (txtPhoneNums <> "") Then
        txtPhoneNums.ForeColor = vbBlack
        txtPhoneNums.FontBold = False
    End If
Else
     txtPhoneNums.Text = "NO CONTACT DETAILS"
     txtPhoneNums.ForeColor = vbRed
     txtPhoneNums.FontBold = True
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

would :

```
txtPhoneNums = txtPhoneNums & "Work: " & strWorkNo
```

not work?

Comment: Hi, thanks guys.  Didn't think of this!  It works fine, but it turns out it's not what I need.  As the value currently in txtPhoneNums may not be relevant to the current record, and I end up adding someone else's details.  I wrote a considerably larger chunk of code that got around this though (without concatenate).  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

In VB6, you concatenate strings with the `&` operator as you say. I don't remember there being a shorthand `&=` (it's been a while), so you'd need:

```
txtPhoneNums = txtPhoneNums & "Mobile: " & strMobileNo
```

Don't think there's a better way.

Answer (score 2):

@David's & @Brant's answers are correct. However, if you find yourself doing a lot of concatenations, then you can build a class to make things easier for you.
Something like: txtPhoneNums.Add("Mobile: ", strMobileNo). I use one to build my SQL statements.

Comment: great suggestion. It is a very clumsy / bulky process in terms of necessary syntax - so building a method would at least slim up the code a bit

Comment: You could write one, or you could use an excellent, fast, free one that already exists. E.g. Karl Peterson's [VB6 StrBldr](http://vb.mvps.org/samples/StrBldr/)

Answer (score 0):

VB6 uses `&` to concatenate strings

Comment: The question already has answers from 8 years ago and yours recent answer adds nothing new in comparison.