# How would I add a string to textbox without clearing its contents VB6

Tags: string, textbox, vb6, append

How would I go about adding a string to this textbox without wiping it of it's contents?

```
For counter = 1 To 5 Step 1
If lengthofdeck(counter) >= length_user Then
  txtresult.Text = nameofdeck(counter)
  MsgBox ("Value: " & length_user & nameofdeck(counter) & " meets or exceeds the size requirement given")
End If
Next counter
```

Answer (score 2):

**Change this line**

txtresult.Text = nameofdeck(counter)

**To this:**

txtresult.Text = txtresult.Text & nameofdeck(counter)

This will allow you to append text.

See this article as well: [Concatenate strings with vb6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10688602/concatenate-strings-with-vb6)

Comment: I dont think VB6 implemented `+=`, it should be the long form

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is:

```
txtresult.SelText = "New Text"
```

This efficiently appends new data to the `TextBox` without needing to reassign the whole string.

By default this inserts at the caret position, if you cannot guarantee this is at the end you make it so with:

```
txtresult.SelStart = Len(txtresult.Text)
```

Calling this also ensures that the most recently added text is visible and not bellow the current scroll position.

Comment: Best if you don't mind confusing/infuriating users who might be interating with the text box at the time.

Comment: Just use `txtresult.SelStart = &H7FFF` without accessing the expensive `Text` property. VB6 textboxes can't handle more than 2^15 symbols.

Comment: .SelStart=&H7FFF works great, initially to make sure that text is added at the right position, then to scroll down to the end after inserting text. And .SelText = "new text" works great. I did not do any testing to see if this performs better than .Text = .Text & "new text"; but seems like it should, depending on what is going on behind the covers with .SelText.